# How to run angular Application without node.js

Tags: node.js, angular, asp.net-core

I want to create the Angular application using Visual Studio 2019 Angular template in Asp.net core but **without Node.js as External tool installation**. I found that NuGet package manager also providing Node.js and NPM Packages for building Angular app.
So I created the asp.net core projected and selected Angular Template and add NuGet **Node.js 5.3.0** that too is saying in readme.txt "Node.js itself is deployed by NuGet, so there is no need to install it locally on dev machines or build servers."
But when I tried to run the angular project then build is failing.
If anyone knows the solution with exact steps so please help me on this.

Comment: How is the build failing? What message are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one extra step is required after the **Nuget Node.js** package installed in the project, which is missing in the node.js document.
Step: Add node.js installed path in **PATH Environment Variable** (One-time activity per dev system)

`e.g: set PATH=%PATH%; C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeJs`

or node.js install path can be set manually in the PATH Environment Variable